# What version of Internet Explorer is built into Pocket PC 4.20 (build 14053)?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I'm trying to find the IE version that's on a mobile device with 'Pocket PC 4.20' (shown on the About screen).

Also what's the official brand of this OS, is it 'Pocket PC 2002' or 'Windows Mobile 2003'?

I was hoping to get jQuery Mobile running on it but it doesn't seem to work, nor does the standard jQuery library.

The user-agent sent by the browser is IE 4.01

Comment: Very interesting. I have an idea at least subsets of jquery should be possible to get running on that, but I don't know really...

Comment: I'm not sure about the IE version, but [this site](http://pocketpccentral.net/help/which_version_wm.htm) suggests that the OS is considered to be "Windows Mobile 2003"

Comment: Thanks, the image check suggests WM 2003 SE but the version check suggests WM 2003 (not SE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly equivalent to IE6. Certainly nothing newer, but could even be older. I wouldn't rule out either IE5.5 or 5.0.

You might get some clues by examining the UserAgent string in your server logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - useragent confirms IE 4.01

Comment: 4.01??? Ouch. Even worse than I thought. What were Microsoft thinking releasing an IE4-based platform in 2003?????? That pretty much kills your plans of using JQuery (or much else, for that matter). If you thought IE6 was bad.....

Comment: Haha yes unfortunately it certainly does rule out jQuery and AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia's Internet Explorer Mobile article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile) suggests that it'll be Pocket Internet Explorer 4 given that the OS (4.20) [should be](http://pocketpccentral.net/help/which_version_wm.htm) Windows Mobile 2003, and "Internet Explorer Mobile" wasn't released until much later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as simon143 has illustrated, assuming this is a Windows device, version 4.20.x refers to Windows Mobile 2003. However, if the device says its WIndows CE, then thats a different thing. Windows Mobile or Pocket PC are specific implementations and configurations of WIndows CE. If it says CE on the device, then each application could be different versions.  Sorry, that doesnt answer your question directly, and may muddy the water a little, but might account for why individual things dont work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Pocket PC 4.20 would refer to Windows Mobile 2003. And I believe that included [Pocket Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile) 4. It would have less capabilities than IE6, as that only became available in Windows Mobile 6.5 with Internet Explorer Mobile 6.

jQuery Mobile does not officially support any Windows Mobile versions before Windows Phone 7, so I think you're out of luck, especially on an old platform like WM2003.

Comment: Thanks, the useragent says it's IE 4.01.